# Jetty 6 -> Jetty 7.5+ gives "No such servlet" exception

Tags: servlets, jetty

My project runs great on Jetty 6, however on Jetty 7.5+ (I checked 7.5, 8.1 and 9.0) I get `No such servlet` exception on Jetty startup (project deployment, I guess).

**web.xml**

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TestServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myproject.servlets.TestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

**TestServlet.java**

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3992344538270432732L;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello Servlet Get</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }   
}
```

Comment: sorry, need some clue as to how you are running and deploying into jetty

Comment: Add the stacktrace also.

Comment: And more detail on your `TestServlet.java`, particularly the `package` and `import` lines.

Comment: And the complete `web.xml` including the XML prolog and doctypes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reversing the order inside web.xml solved the problem:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myproject.servlets.TestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TestServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I guess previous versions of Jetty were not so strict about the order of servlet declarations.

Comment: Your `web.xml` has a DTD that should help to validate and enforce that order.